# Is there any way to run first base function that defined in ajaxSetup?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function onSuccess(msg) {
        // add some functions to `msg` 
        // then return to success method that defined in $.ajax 
        msg.display = function(){
            alert(msg.M_Prop);
        }

        return msg;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    success: function(newMsg){
        // call new functions of newMsg object
        newMsg.display();
    }
});
```

Comment: `success` takes only `function()` and not something like `success: function onSuccess(msg){...}` or did I missed something?

Comment: success takes `function` and i am giving a function in ajaxSetup. It is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  url: "http://jsfiddle.net",
  global: false,
  type: "GET",
  display: function(msg) { // custom display function defined in ajax setup
    alert(msg);
  }
});

$.ajax({
  success: function(newMsg){
     this.display("Hello: " + newMsg); //call it in your success handler
  }
});
```

I've tested it here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dcgqe/)

Here's another way (the way you want it)

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
       url: "http://jsfiddle.net",
       global: false,
       type: "GET",
       success: function(msg) {
           msg = msg || {};
           msg.display = function() {
             alert("display");
           }
           if(typeof(this.customSuccess) === "function") { 
              this.customSuccess(msg); // call the custom success function
           }
       }
     });

    $.ajax({
        customSuccess: function(newMsg){ // define custom success function
            newMsg.display();
        }
    });
```

Tested this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JCMqb/)

Comment: But msg didn't change(added new functions etc.) . But this also looks goods.